# Can VMware PLayer Workstation (free) run multiple VMs at at time?

Tags: linux, vmware-player

That may be a simple one, but I have several VMs created under VMware. I have a couple of versions of Windows as well as some installs ofdistros of Linux. My VMware player runs under Ubuntu Linux 16.04. The problem is that when I start the VMware player, it offers the installed VMs, but this disappears when I start the first one, and I cannot seem to get it back so I can start another VM for, say, Linux. How can I solve this issue ? I have the latest version of VMware Player available for personal (free) use.

Thanks :-)

Comment: You can run VMPlayer more than once - thus more than one VM at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply open one more VMPlayer in launcher and thus can use multiple VM machines simultaneously. I am using two VMWare Workstation 14 Player in ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

No. I manage the business for this product, and it does not allow you to run more than 1 VM at a time by design.  What you want is VMware Workstation Pro.

From the [VMWare Player Manual](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwarePlayerManual10.pdf)

> Note: VMware Player can run only one virtual machine at a time. You must close the virtual machine currently running in VMware Player before you can open another virtual machine.

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/VMwarePlayerManual10.pdf

"Note: VMware Player can run only one virtual machine at a time. You must close the virtual machine currently running in VMware Player before you can open another virtual machine."

Comment: What a shame.  Perhaps VBox is a better option if you're not  big company and only want to run pen tests on 5 or 6 VMs